# SSH.NET passwd not executing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ssh, ssh.net

I can't seem to make this library to work.
I'm doing something pretty straightforward but still I can't manage to do it.

```
            client.Connect();
            client.RunCommand("sudo passwd test");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            client.RunCommand("testtest");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            client.RunCommand("12345");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            client.RunCommand("12345");
            bool primera = true;
            client.Disconnect();
```

If I try then to login with test using the credentials just posted it fails. But if I do the same commands through normal SSH through my terminal I can log in.
Why SSH.NET is not executing those commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because after you run `client.RunCommand("sudo passwd test");` a program is running, waiting for input.  The `RunCommand` method won't actually run the command until after the program returns.

I encountered the same problem when trying to run `su - <login>` and found the following workaround...

```
Shell = Client.CreateShellStream("xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);

Reader = new StreamReader(Shell);
Writer = new StreamWriter(Shell);

Writer.AutoFlush = true;

Writer.Write("su - " + login2 + "\n");

while (true)
{
    var output = Reader.ReadLine();

    if (output.EndsWith("Password: "))
    {
        break;
    }
}

Writer.Write(password2 + "\n");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Most important was to use `.Write(... +"\n")` instead of `.WriteLine(...)`